# Use "<" and ">" in a string in php

Tags: php, string, email, special-characters, implode

I have a section in my code looking like this:

```
$accounts[] = array("id" => 1, "fullName"=>"Lorem ipsum", "email"=>"lorem@example.com");
$accounts[] = array("id" => 2, "fullName"=>"Lorema ipsum", "email"=>"lorema@example.com");
$toUsers = array();
foreach($accounts as $account){
    $toUsers[] = $account['fullName'] . "<" . $account['email'] . ">";
}
$toString = implode(", ",$toUsers);
```

This loop is supposed to give me a string, formatted like an email header (I want to use the mail function).
I expect the result to be `$toString = "Lorem ipsum<lorem@example.com>, Lorema ipsum<lorema@example.com>";` but all I get is `$toString = "Lorem ipsum, lorema Ipsum";`

What do I need to do to get "<" and ">" working with a string in php?

Thanks, JNK

Comment: The brackets should be there, but probably you can't see them because of your browser (because it thinks they are HTML tags). See: http://codepad.org/9ehPQ1VL

Comment: Where are you outputting this? In HTML?

Comment: Is it "looking like" or "exactly like"? I've seen issues using `"<?"` and `"<?php"`, but not this.

Comment: @NullUserException Thanks, didn't think it'd be that simple :) looking at the html source code it outputs everything correctly...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Outputting it to an HTML document are we? Chances are your browser's interpreting it as markup. Check the view->source and see if it's there.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing at all. They have no special significance in PHP.

If you are using you PHP to generate HTML, on the other hand, then they will have special significance *in the outputted HTML document*. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

e.g.

```
$toString = htmlspecialchars(implode(", ",$toUsers));
```

Best practice is to convert data for presentation as HTML in this way at the point where you insert the into the HTML document (and not before).

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works exactly as expected. You've probably fixed the mistake by reducing your original code to this post.